# Linear discriminant analysis for non-normal data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I have a classification problem in which the independent variables are not normally distributed.

Is it appropriate to apply linear discriminant analysis for classification? Since lda assumes data to be normal.